# Upgrade from SCVMM 2012 R2 Preview to SCVMM 2012 R2

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, upgrade, scvmm

I currently have `Microsoft System Center 2012 R2 Virtual Machine Manager` the `R2 Preview` version, **3.1.7245.0**. I need to upgrade it to the actual `R2`, non-preview, version **3.2.7510.0**.

Without uninstalling the current one, how could I complete the upgrade?

When trying to run the installer over the existing version it doesn't offer any possibility except to remove.

Comment: I don't know if the preview can be upgraded.  I do know that for the other versions the upgrade was an uninstall of VMM from the server (leaving the database alone),  then you install the new version and connect it to the existing database.

Comment: @E-Rock I have not found any other way upgrade it, except by uninstalling it and installing the `RTM`. I you want to move your comment as an actual answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if the preview can be upgraded. I do know that for the other versions the upgrade was an uninstall of VMM from the server (leaving the database alone), then you install the new version and connect it to the existing database.

Here is the TechNet article on doing the upgrade from 2012 SP1 to R2.
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn469607.aspx